# NPM Error while using the Firebase CLI trying to deploy

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

This is the log of the error:

`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   '%RESOURCE_DIR%',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'lint' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\firebase\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json'
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\bcook\firebase
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--prefix" "%RESOURCE_DIR%" "run" "lint"
8 verbose node v8.10.0
9 verbose npm  v5.6.0
10 error path C:\Users\username\firebase\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json
11 error code ENOENT
12 error errno -4058
13 error syscall open
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\firebase\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json'
15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]`

The first time I ran this, it did this so I created the package.json file empty, no contents whatsoever. I ran this a second time and got this again. Any help? I'm trying to deploy my app to my firebaseapp site.

Comment: Please edit the question to include all the steps you took to create your project, ending at the command that fails like this.

Comment: This is a firebase pre-deploy issue. Check [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/610) for more information and workaround

Comment: @TimMartens Thanks so much! I opened an issue and hopefully it will get resolved soon.